# When I run flutter app on my device I got error

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, sdk, adb

I new in Flutter i want run my first app, but i got this problem

```
Launching lib\main.dart on HUAWEI P7 L10 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.

Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...

Error: ADB exited with exit code -1

Performing Push Install

adb: error: failed to read copy response

 D:\Mobile\AndroidStudioProjects\i_am_rich\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 5.3 MB/s (45878300 bytes in 8.283s)

adb: error: failed to read copy response

Error launching application on HUAWEI P7 L10.
```

And When I run `flutter doctor` I not got any problem `No issues found`

```
D:\Mobile\AndroidStudioProjects\i_am_rich>flutter doctor                                                                                          
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393], locale ru-RU)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.48.0)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Help me please if you know. Thanks.

Comment: hey there, run `flutter upgrade` to upgrade your flutter version and see if the problem persists

Comment: This is helped me in my case. Thanks for answer

Comment: Nice, I used that as an answer, so please mark it as the answer to help others with the same question

Answer (score 1):

Running `flutter upgrade` should fix this